# Capture full request from application

Tags: python, curl

I am writing a Python application which queries several webservers, once per minute per server. The application runs fine for a few minutes, then all the servers start responding with the following error:

> The following cURL error occurred:  The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request

When this happens, I see that my outgoing bandwidth pegs and both CPU cores are working above 80% (nominally very light load on this machine). Memory usage is not significantly affected, however.

Is there any way to capture the entire request for all requests sent from a particular application? Alternatively, in Python can I capture the full request and then output it back for debugging purposes? Here is the part of the code which queries the servers:

```
output = cStringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, output.write)
c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10) 
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 15) 
c.setopt(c.FAILONERROR, True)
c.setopt(c.NOSIGNAL, 1)

try:
    c.perform()
    toReturn = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return toReturn

except pycurl.error, error:
    errno, errstr = error
    print 'The following cURL error occurred: ', errstr
```

The machine is a dual-core 2.0 GHz Intel box with 6 GiB RAM, running Kubuntu 12.10 and Python 2.7. Everything is coded in VIM, so there is no spurious IDE code running amok.

Comment: This is the code to get content from one URL?  How are you requesting multiple URLs? (for loop, threads, etc)

Comment: This code is in a thread. A while loop spans a new thread every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to capture the entire request for all requests sent from a particular application?

The easiest way to capture and monitor all incoming/outcoming traffic, including the requests sent from your application is by using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

> Alternatively, in Python can I capture the full request and then output it back for debugging purposes?

You can add the following debug option so that curl prints some useful information about the request:

> c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)